# Format table with CSS

Tags: css

I have a table and I want to use CSS to create at least 1 cell space between text and table border - how do I achieve this???

Comment: Cell spacing is uncountable. What do you mean by "1 cell space"?

Comment: What do you mean by "1 cell space"? You'll probably end up applying padding to tds, but maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

use `pedding` property of css.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what a "cell space" is, but somthing like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td style="padding:30px;">my content</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to pad the cell?

In that case (something like):

```
td {
  padding:1px;
}
```

Comment: I mean there is distance between the contents of the table and the table's borders.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following CSS to your table:

```
table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Substitute whatever value you want for the padding.